# "(intermediate.value).apply is not a function" on Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm running this

`$(sysLazyImage).on('load', $(sysLazyImage).fadeIn(1000));`

and am getting the console error mentioned in the title.

I believe it might be due to a missing semi-colon, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: is sysLazyImage a class name or id or something?

Comment: `$(sysLazyImage).on('load', function(){$(sysLazyImage).fadeIn(1000)});`

Comment: Please post as answer, for credit.